# Processor ticks count for windows thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

How can I know how many processor ticks used by thread. For example, if i understand correctly, if thread in sleep, it isn't using processor ticks. I'm writing program, that watch for process in windows, and its threads. And I need to know, that my thread is working or not. Exit code information isn't enough for me. How I can know this information from thread `HANDLE`?

Answer (score 1):

What about GetThreadTimes. It will return the times...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237

Comment: Welcome to SO @Jochen.  Some guidance, we are pretty strict about the desired format of answers.  You can't ask a question to answer a question and an answer that isn't much more than a link to another web site isn't considered a valid answer.  Check Roman's answer for a decent way to provide documentation that doesn't rely on a link that could go dead at any time.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for your guidance... I will try to improve my answers in the future... I am new to SO, so I will have to learn...

Comment: @JochenKalmbach if i understand correctly, if program is working, this times should changing, but i dont see this :(

Comment: @EXTRAM: See also the comments to the other answer... For normal szenarios, it should give you the correct values. How detailed do you want the times?

Answer (score 1):

[GetThreadTimes function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), take a look at kernel/user times you can obtain for a given thread:

> lpKernelTime [out]
>
> A pointer to a FILETIME structure that receives the amount of time that the thread has executed in kernel mode. lpUserTime [out]
>
> A pointer to a FILETIME structure that receives the amount of time that **the thread has executed in user mode**.

Also, if you watch threads using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), you can see these times changing:

[image]

Comment: Also be aware that GetThreadTimes" might give you a wrong number in some special situations. The thread time is only calculated if the thread uses its whole qunatum. See also [Why GetThreadTimes is wrong](http://blog.kalmbachnet.de/?postid=28)

Comment: @JochenKalmbach: You are certainly correct. There is also `QueryThreadCycleTime` for the punctilious, but I'd say `GetThreadTimes` is good for the majority of scenarios, and in particular for watching threads from a side observer app.

Comment: Yes, for most of the scenarios `GetThreadTimes` is sufficient!